# How to vertically stretch an image responsively?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I am trying to implement a **sidemenu with a background image** but I don't understand how to make it responsive also vertically...
I have this image https://ibb.co/Pzyyyh2 whose size is *320x1000px*. It's a very tall white image that a certain point becomes black. 
I'd like to have this black detail to **stay always at a certain point of my sidemenu** (the transition from white to black should start before the social link part).

As you can see here, on **iPhone X** emulator, it works as expected: https://ibb.co/C7Nm6b7.
While on another device such as **Moto G4** this happens: https://ibb.co/S7tQwJV

Comment: Why do you use an image for this task? `skew()` on an black div would help too

Comment: @Ifaruki wow thanks, I didn't know the existance of skew() at all! So basically it allows me to create that oblique effect without using an image and so being automatically responsive, isn't it?
I should use it on social links menu right?

Comment: Yea its better, and your page should be fsster because it hasnt to download the whole image. I would use an black div, `skew()` him, put an absolute position on him and place him on the bottom

Comment: @Ifaruki I'm implementing it and it seems to be way better as you said! Just a thing, since skew div is oblique, it will naturally overflow. I need to avoid this behaviour but adding `overflow-y:hidden` doesn't help...do you have any clue?
Ex. here: https://ibb.co/dWBJ38f

Comment: Use overflow hidden on the parent and move the skew element with translateY down

Comment: Just for funzles, but you can also make an 'triangle' edge in e.g. a separate div or a pseudo element by only using borders. `width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 0; border-left: 0; border-bottom: 40px solid black; border-right: 300px solid transparent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the white part of the image, if what you're trying to show is the black, then just use the black. If your image is an svg, it will always expand/contract properly, without visible pixelation. The rest of the footer should have a background-color equal to that of your img.

If you want to use skew, then make a first div (the parent/wrapper), then place it right before your footer area. Then inside the wrapper, add the skew-div. Make the parent have overflow:hidden so the excess of the skew-siv  doesn't become visible past the borders of the parent.

Like this:

[image]

Then, inside your 'magic-div', you'd have the following:

[image]

The parent gets width: 100%; and overflow:hidden;. The child skew div inside gets width:100%; too. If you're using background with an svg as suggested earlier, the background-size rule should be 100% auto or cover, depending on the scenario (the widths you're covering + the angle of your skew). Give it a try and let us know how it went.